# Is it safe to apply autofix from ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'd like to format several files but I'm worried about **breaking code**.

When I'm saying if it is safe for not, I'm saying that the execution of the code before and after is exactly the same.

For instance, there are rules that look pretty safe to be applied (like indenting). I suppose that changing the number of spaces won't affect the execution of the code.

Then, there are rules that don't look so safe. For instance, changing var to let or const could cause a different execution as var is not exactly the same as let.

So, I'm wondering if there are any auto-fix rule from ESLint that can change the code so the execution is different when applied the `--fix` thing.

Comment: @num8er I extended the question with more details. Should I add something else?

Comment: I've retracted close and downvote, now it's ok. About autofix-ing: I use it often and I've such scripts in my package.json that eases my life: http://joxi.ru/L2133QH8K691rX

Comment: The authors of the individual plugins are encouraged to only make changes that are safe and do not break the code. But there might be plugins that explicitly do not do that. You could look at Issue [eqeqeq: Don't autofix #4578](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4578) to see a discussion about the `===`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, because the `--fix` flag does not fix all your JS issues [1].
So you have to fix some eslint warnings/errors yourself.

[1] https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--fix

Answer (score 4):

Mostly yes, but I recently came across an issue when using the autofix option. The codebase I work with uses Mithril v.0.2, which initializes the component's controller using the `new` keyword. The new keyword only works on constructors, but the `eslint --fix` command (specifically the `prefer-arrow-callback` replaced some of my anonymous functions with arrow functions. Which caused some errors, since arrow functions are not constructors.

So my case was like this:

```js
const component = {};
// My method in this object used to be a regular function like the one below
component.normalFunction = function () {
    return {
        test: true
    };
}

// Eslint autofix changed it to be an arrow function
component.arrowFunction = () => {
    return {
        test: true
    };
}

try {
  new component.normalFunction();
  new component.arrowFunction();
} catch (err) {
  document.body.prepend(err);
}
```

So far that was the only issue I have found with the autofix rule. In my case I ran eslint autofix excluding that rule.